# Django REST Framework: Specify data type of SerializerMethodField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

It seems SerializerMethodField assumes the data type of the field is a string, even if it is an int.  For instance, I have this field:

```
num_sections = serializers.SerializerMethodField(help_text="The number of sections for this course")

def get_num_sections(self, obj) -> int:
    return obj.sections.count()
```

However, in the auto-generated OpenAPI schema, this field shows up as a string field.  Is there any way to set the proper data type for a SerializerMethodField?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this snippet:

```
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema_field

num_sections = serializers.SerializerMethodField(help_text="The number of sections for this course")

@extend_schema_field(serializers.IntegerField)
def get_num_sections(self, obj) -> int:
    return obj.sections.count()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a heavy-handed solution, but this works for me:

```
num_sections = type('SerializerMethodField', (serializers.SerializerMethodField, serializers.IntegerField), dict())(
        help_text="The number of sections for this course")

def get_num_sections(self, obj) -> int:
    return obj.sections.count()
```

The 3 argument type function can be used as a shorthand for making a child of two classes.

Please let me know if anyone has any better solutions or comments on this.

Comment: It is work with drf-yasg.

Comment: drf-yasg is deprecated, better to use drf_spectacular with extend_schema_field decorator.